# Oledb + excel + HDR =NO. ¿Como hacer selects?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

La cosa es que quiero hacer Selects en Excel, de cualquier forma posible, no me vale interop ya que la hoja es dinámica, un día puede tener 340 registros, otro día 20.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es algo tipo:

```
Select count(*) From [Sheet$] Where id=12312
```

Por poner un ejemplo. Sé que este tipo de consulta no tendría sentido, pero para entendernos.

> Ejemplo de estructura de la tabla.

**La tabla real es más compleja, tiene más columnas cuyos nombres tienen espacios.**

[image: Ejemplo de estructura]

Esta es la conexión que tengo creada y lo que he intentado hasta ahora, pero no me ha dado resultado, entre otros intentos parecidos. 
    OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr;

```
MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='D:\\nombre.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'");
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM [Hoja1$]";
dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
     resultados.Add(dr.GetString(1)); //List<String> resultados = new List<String>();
}
```

Alguna forma de filtrar los datos?

Comment: Un bucle for desde i=3 hasta resultados.length-1 no te valdría?

Comment: Tendrían que ser varios bucles... lo he pensado, pero a no ser que encuentre alguna otra forma, creo que mejor dejaré esto así.

Comment: `for i=0;i<resultados.Length-1;i++) { myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE[Aux$] set Valor=" + resultados[i] + " where cod=" +(i+3).ToString();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();}` ?

Comment: Tendría que hacer unos cuantos for....  creo que para futuras ocasiones lo dejaré así, por si en algún momento cambia la estructura del excel tenerlo más controlado, por que no es únicamente una vez. No sé como explicarlo :S cada  vez que en la imagen ves un naranja o algo que no está en blanco es un salto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el Interop del Excel y acceder a las celdas de la hoja con coordenadas fila-columna sin tener que hacer consultas sql.
Mira este ejemplo:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

Comment: No me aparece el interop al buscar en referencias, ya he buscado en todos los sitios que podía.

Comment: Tienes que tener instalado el office-excel, es la unida pega